# Not able to dismissModalViewController from parentView which has a UIActivityIndicatorController

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Here my method for starting animation of the activity indicator:

```
-(void)showLoadingView{

CGRect transparentViewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,1024,768);
transparentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:transparentViewFrame];
transparentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
transparentView.alpha = 0.7;

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
spinner.frame = CGRectMake(1024/2, 728/2, 40, 40);
spinner.center = transparentView.center;
[spinner startAnimating];

UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(spinner.frame.origin.x+60, 
                                                                  spinner.frame.origin.y-30, 150, 100)];
messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
messageLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24];
messageLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
messageLabel.text = @"Loading...";

[transparentView addSubview:spinner];
[transparentView addSubview:messageLabel];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:transparentView];

[messageLabel release];
[spinner release];
[transparentView release]; 
}
```

And here is how and where I call it to start, and dismiss:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self showLoadingView];

[super viewDidLoad];
[self init];
[self createBarButtonItems];
[self createTableView];

[self parseResponse: [NSString stringWithFormat:services.filterURL,[filterOptions objectAtIndex:0],
                      [filterOptions objectAtIndex:1]]];

[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But the modal view never gets dismissed, and the indicator never stops. Can anyone please help me with this. My goal is basically on loading the application it will fill screen with a UIView that is transparent, and over that I have the indicator which starts right away, and stops after parsing my response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` only works if you've previously used `presentModalViewController:animated:` to show one. In this case you've just added a UIView to the view hierarchy.

Create an instance variable to hold an instance of transparent view. Set up the instance variable in `-showLoadingView`, then when its done simply remove it from the view like so...

`[transparentView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: that seemed to work, thanks! but what I did was instead of creating an instance to hold transparentView, I just released transparentView in dealloc rather then in my showLoadingView method, and I simply removed transparentView itself from the superview. Is this okay?

Comment: so I thought it was working, but apparently now it never really shows up. Not sure whats going on because when I comment the line to removeFromSuperview, it appears. But when I uncomment it, it never appears, and I made sure to put a sleep for like 5 seconds and still don't see it show up. Very weird.